# How to web scrape from youtube using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube, user-input

Code trilas:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import json
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) //used to choose options from chrome//
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
baseurl = 'http://youtube.com'
keyword = input() #user input as earth
driver.get(f'{baseurl}/search?q= {keyword}')
```

I want to **scrape** data from the site http://youtube.com

Comment: ...okay? You've showed us some code. Do you have a question? Please read [ask].

Comment: Please tell us what data you want to get from this website and we will try to help you.

Comment: i want to get the link,like,dislike,number of views data from youtube using python

Comment: i am using jupyter it's showing error as im using chrome to connect the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the titles of the youtube search results using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  baseurl = "http://youtube.com"
  keyword = input()
  driver.get(f'{baseurl}/search?q={keyword}')
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-video-renderer' and @aria-label]")))])
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  earth
  ['Lil Dicky - Earth (Official Music Video)', 'The History of Earth - How Our Planet Formed - Full Documentary HD', "EARTH FROM SPACE: Like You've Never Seen Before", 'Lil Dicky - Earth (Lyrics)', 'Michael Jackson - Earth Song (Official Video)', 'Lil Dicky - Earth (CLEAN CENSORED VERSION)', 'Marshmello ft. Bastille - Happier (Official Music Video)', 'USA for Africa - We are the World', 'Lil Dicky - Freaky Friday feat. Chris Brown (Official Music Video)', 'What if Pluto Hits The Earth?', "15 Places on Earth Where Gravity Doesn't Seem to Work", 'Earth 101 | National Geographic', 'How Earth Moves', 'History Of Earth In 9 Minutes', 'What Happens If 1 mm Black Hole Appears On Earth?', 'Planet Earth seen from space (Full HD 1080p) ORIGINAL']
  ```

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home {when running this code on jupyter this error is coming}

Comment: @KavitaNegi That is a different issue all together. You need to change the path of chromedriver from `C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe` to the value as per your system. Else you can you raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-16-353ab2c57807>", line 10
    baseurl =  'http://youtube.com'
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @KavitaNegi replaced single quotes with double quotes, please retest and let me know the status.

Comment: same error File "<ipython-input-1-2d76dbb2c81c>", line 10
    baseurl =  "http://youtube.com"
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax